# LineBreak within an excel cell using GemBox Spreadsheet

Tags: gembox-spreadsheet

Is it possible to add a line break within an excel cell using the GemBox Spreadsheet API? For example if you're in Excel you can press Alt+Enter and go to a new line in a cell. I'm having trouble finding a property on the CellStyle class in GemBox that allows this. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, for example try the following:

```cs
var ef = new ExcelFile();
var ws = ef.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Sample";
ws.Cells["A1"].Value += "\n" + "Sample";

ef.Save("Sample.xlsx");
```

In short, just use the new line character in `ExcelCell.Value`.
Note that when you're assigning such a value, GemBox.Spreadsheet will automatically set `ExcelCell.Style.WrapText` property to `true`.